# Copying over sites/folders from one cpanel to another on a same server

Tags: cpanel, migration, whm

I am in a VPS enviroment where I have migrated my sites from a shared hosting company to a new VPS hosting.

I now have 2 cpanels in WHM.  One is the one I created in WHM that cantains no files/fodlers/sites (cpanel-1), the other cpanel is what I migrated from old hosting company (cpanel-2).

I want copy over a site from cpanel-2 where the folder is .../public_html/site1.com   to cpanel-1  /public_html/

I connect through SSH to cpanel-1 but I dont see anything about fils/folder in cpanel-2.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: Is there are reason you aren't using the cpanel transfer tool in WHM?

Comment: I don't see any "cpanel transfer" tool in WHM!?  is there such a thing?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/bd0d74aaa5a76bdffa6a59cb61fe3fde Version 68.0.19 but it has been included for a long time.

Comment: I located what you're referring to but I'm not sure it would do what I need.  Under Transfer -> Copy an Account From Another Server With an Account Password is what I chose and transferred my domains (which I have one main domain and other domains under it) which brought all domains under one cpanel.  Now I'm trying to have a cpanel for each of those domains.

Comment: Oh, I misread your original post.  You will need a separate hosting account for each site.

Comment: WHM will give you capability to have multiple cpanels.  As I created couple already.